# M1 macbook air screen turn of on lowering brightness below minimum?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, apple-silicon

I can lower my brightness of my macboook lower then the minimum level which turns of the display. Tried restarting the device but It didnt fix it .

Answer (score 4):

This is correct functionality. When you turn it to zero, the backlight turns off. The display is still showing content.

To resolve this issue, raise the screen brightness by pressing brightness-up key on your keyboard. If you have the regular keys disabled in favor of Fn keys, you may need to hold <kbd>fn</kbd> while you press the brightness-up key.